# Captcha not visible Create Account or Login, but is visible Forgot Password

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to get Captcha to work on "Create an Account" without any luck.
The capchta image is not visible nor is "Please type the letters below" text or text box.

If you try to create an account you get the error "Incorrect CAPTCHA"

The strange thing is it works perfectly on the "Forgot Your Password" form.

Comment: I have found the problem.
This was caused by IWD One Page Check out.
Un-installed the module and its now working.

Comment: please put this as answr